# Is it possible to make turtle.Screen() background transparent?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Is it possible to make `turtle.Screen()` background transparent?
If not then how to draw lines on screen? 
I want to create program which gives me hints on pool game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since turtle is built atop tkinter, if we work with an *embedded* turtle, rather than *standalone*, then your ability to create a transparent turtle window is a function of your version of the Tk library and your operating system platform:

```
import tkinter as tk
from turtle import RawTurtle, TurtleScreen, ScrolledCanvas

root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes("-alpha", 0.3)

canvas = ScrolledCanvas(root)
canvas.pack()

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)

turtle = RawTurtle(screen)
turtle.width(10)

turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(-100)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.circle(100)

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

In other words, "maybe".

Answer (score 0):

The essence of this answer is the same as @cdlane's answer: obtain a reference to the Tk root window, and set its transparency with `myroot.attributes('-alpha', 0.3)`. cdlane's answer obtains the rootwindow by starting from Tk, and constructing all the necessary Tk objects before constructing a TurtleScreen and Turtle. This answer starts from the other end: it allows `turtle` to initialise the Tk objects it needs, and traverses object references to get from the turtle to the Tk root window.

Both answers then set the Tk root window's transparency. Which method is more useful depends on your usecase.

Code (made to be as similar to cdlane's as possible):

```
from turtle import *

turtle = getturtle()

# This does not have to come before the drawing code --
# you can alter window transparency at any moment.    
root = (turtle
    ._screen
    .getcanvas()
    .winfo_toplevel())
root.attributes('-alpha', 0.3)

turtle.width(10)

turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(-100)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.circle(100)
```